# Retrieve, from a failed wifi hotspot connection attempt, the password posted

Tags: android

I want to get the wrong password that a user enters at a wifi hotspot on android.
I just want to know if this is possible on android and if so how.

Comment: Just to clarify, this is the Android box acting as a hotspot, right? With what protocol? Do you have root access?

Comment: And by the way, I disagree with closing this question as “break the security of a specific system for you” — this question isn't about breaking a specific system, it's about the leakage of information in a particular scenario. I voted to close as unclear as per my comment above, and would vote to reopen if you answer my questions.

Answer (score 1):

If you could do that easily, consider that you will be able to get easily the correct password.

TL;DR: no it isn't possible.

There are attacks where an user may compromise the password from a wifi hotspot, but mostly these are possible because we get large amounts of encrypted packages (this is a simplification, obviously you also need a bug in the implementation of the security mechanism).

Consider that when trying to access with an invalid password you only have one package so the only way to exploit it would be brute force.

In fact, it seems harder to get an specific erroneous password than the good one.

Comment: I think the question was about the case where the Android box is the hotspot (and so in particular it has the correct password; the question is whether it sees incorrect passwords).